# What is the lambda referring to in the OpenCV Mat::t Documentation example?

Tags: c++, opencv

Here is how its used in the Documentation at this link http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?highlight=mat%3A%3At#mat-t

```
 Mat A1 = A + Mat::eye(A.size(), A.type)*lambda;
 Mat C = A1.t()*A1; // compute (A + lambda*I)^t * (A + lamda*I)
```

Is the lambda referring to a general mathematical function named "lambda" or is there an actual 'MatExpr' function named lambda...If so I couldn't find it.  I looked over google and the Opencv Documentation with no hits...I just found in math(generally) lambda could refer to one of 5 mathematical functions, at wolfram math or a lambda matrix [here](http://www.solitaryroad.com/c152.html)

I tried running the above example and get a few errors.. I'd like to run this example so I can more easily break into higher math because I completely understand whats going on in the example above save for the lambda part. Since it's tied to an equation,  getting this part would help me experiment more in that realm. can anyone help me run it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lambda seems to be just a scalar factor here.

imho, the whole expression is only there to highlight that:

```
Mat::eye(A.size(), A.type())*lambda;
```

is equivalent to :

```
I * lambda
```

---

just try on your own:

```
Mat A(3,3,CV_32F);
Mat I_mul_3 = Mat::eye(A.size(), A.type())*3;
cerr << I_mul_3 << endl;

[3, 0, 0;
 0, 3, 0;
 0, 0, 3]
```

---

but you're right, there's a typo there, should be

```
Mat::eye(A.size(), A.type());
```

instead of:

```
Mat::eye(A.size(), A.type);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering  my question.  Can you tell me, is lambda usually a catch all placeholder in functions that can mean anything like 'x' usually is? If so would you know of a link to online resource so I can read more about it...I didn't notice much on google to that effect.

Comment: well, in this case it's a placeholder only. still, as 
@Çağatay Murat 's answer tries to point out, lambda might denote e.g. eigenvalues in another context

Comment: I'll watch the video and the link and try pick something up...but any chance yo can direct me to hard evidence of a specific answer I'm trying to learn math in conjunction with programming so a specific answer right would really help now.  If you haven't studied much math just pretend this answer was for the next guy that looks at this post. Your answer so far really did give me some direction and that's why I accepted it. Will watch the video and read the page  and post back If I find out something

Comment: Sorry about that,  I noticed you did give a specific answer..Thanks again for clarifying your answer..Have a Good day

Comment: This use of lambda here seems to be as a regularization factor to make the system easier to solve, and to avoid numerically unstable solutions.  The use of the greek letter lambda for that role is common in optimization.

Answer (score 0):

Nıot sure but it can be used as a eigenvalue. eigenvalues and eigenvectors are widely being used in matrix opetions. Look [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G4N8vJpf7hM) video and [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors) wikipedia page.